# How to view registers values in string

Tags: radare2, strings, register

Is it possible that radare2 will show registers values also in strings ?

For example, when I run `ar` I am getting the liste of registers and I have:

```
rax = 0x000000042
```

Is there a way to also show next to it the string value ?
Something like that:

```
rax = 0x000000042   ; 'B'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `drr` is showing the strings.